# Custom css file for all pages under a specific url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website that has 2 sections each with different css and specific urls (ie. testsite.com/one/ and testsite.com/two/) I need to apply specific style sheets to each of those urls and all paths falling under those (ie testsite.com/one/test testsite.com/one/test2 and so forth) so for testsite.com/one/* all would get a css file named one.css and for testsite.com/two/* all would get a css file names two.css

```html
<?php 
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
 if ( is_page( 'two') ) {
    // If page matches, then load the following files
    wp_enqueue_style('two', get_template_directory_uri().'/two.css',false,'1','screen' );
   // If the condition tag does not match...
   } else {
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );?>
```

Problem with this is that it only applies the css file to testsite.com/two and nothing past that for example testsite.com/two/xx or testsite.com/two/bbb I need to get the css file to apply to every directory including and following testsite.com/two/ Does that make sense?

Comment: First of all, how did you create the /one and /two? Are those Custom Post Types, Categories or Tags?

Comment: Yes those are pages. Nested under them are child pages. Two > Child 1 > Child 2 etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try checking whether the requested URI contains a string identifying your "sub site".

*Code now extended to demo else, elesif and "or" to cover follow on questions in comments. questions in comments.*

```
 function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
   global $post;   
   $perma = get_permalink( $post->ID );  // or use get_page_uri??

   if (strpos($perma, '/two/') !== false  || strpos($perma, '/anything/') !== false) {
      wp_enqueue_style('two', get_template_directory_uri().'/two.css',false,'1','screen' );
   } 
   elseif (strpos($perma, '/THREE/') !== false) {
      wp_enqueue_style('three', get_template_directory_uri().'/THREE.css',false,'1','screen' );
   }
   else {  // if you want to enqueue some default CSS for all other pages
      wp_enqueue_style('default', get_template_directory_uri().'/default.css',false,'1','screen' );
   }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: Alright what if I wanted to add another string? Such as /one/?

Comment: Thanks for accepting ans. For multiple css options you can extend the if statement into an "if (one) else (two)" or "if (three) elseif (two) else (one)" etc.  You use an "if else" in your questions example.

Comment: Adding additional strings to show the same css file? ```if (strpos($perma, '/two/' || '/another/') !== false) {
      wp_enqueue_style('two', get_template_directory_uri().'/two.css',false,'1','screen' );
   }``` Does not work what is the correct "or" statement here?

Comment: I've modified original answer to cover ||, elseif and else. Integer 0 and string "0" are evaluated as FALSE by PHP all other string/int values eavaluate as true if you don't place '/another/' in its OWN strpos function it will always cause the or clause to evaluate as TRUE.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but the idea would be to locate the top level ancestor and compare against that post/pages title.

```
$post = get_post();
if ($post->post_parent) {
    $ancestors=get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
    $root=count($ancestors)-1;
    $parent = $ancestors[$root];
} else {
    $parent = $post->ID;
}

if(strtolower(get_the_title($parent)) == 'two') {
    wp_enqueue_style('two', get_template_directory_uri().'/two.css',false,'1','screen' );
}
```

Comment: No luck. It only applied to the first page. Would it have to do with that this is using "post" instead of "page"?

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on whether or not you are specifying the sub-pages have a parent page.  Or if they are simply within that path.

If the sub-pages have a page specified as a parent, you can do this:

```
// for the number, use the ID of the parent page

if ( is_page( 'one' ) || '1' == $post->post_parent ) {    
    // the page is "one", or the parent of the page is "one"
    wp_enqueue_style('one', get_template_directory_uri().'/one.css',false,'1','screen' );
}

if ( is_page( 'two' ) || '2' == $post->post_parent ) {    
    // the page is "two", or the parent of the page is "two"
    wp_enqueue_style('two', get_template_directory_uri().'/two.css',false,'1','screen' );
}
```

If there is no parent specified you'll need to check for the permalink as was noted above by scytale.